# Unbeatable minimax checkers algorithm

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax

Is it possible to program an artificial intelligence algorithm for checkers, using minimax, that cannot be beaten?

Comment: I think another way of asking this question is: `"Is it possible to have a draw in checkers?"` This is equivalent because if you *did* create an unbeatable algorithm, and you loaded it on two computers, which computer would win? It would only be unbeatable if draws are possible in checkers.

Comment: Per the link, "More recently, in 2007 scientists at the University of Alberta[17] developed their "Chinook" program to the point where it is unbeatable."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts

Comment: To be precise, though, Chinook is not minimax. Rather [Chinook's program algorithm includes an opening book, a library of opening moves from games played by grandmasters; a deep search algorithm; a good move evaluation function; and an end-game database for all positions with eight pieces or fewer. The linear handcrafted evaluation function considers several features of the game board, including piece count, kings count, trapped kings, turn, runaway checkers (unimpeded path to be kinged) and other minor factors.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinook_(draughts_player))

Answer (score 0):

Either, yes [because someone already programmed an unbeatable computer](http://www.engadget.com/2007/07/21/checkers-program-unbeatable-by-humans-other-computers/) (and you'd just be duplicating the algorithm in a different language) or no *because it impossible to beat, even by other computers.*